# How to stop terminal from closing automatically and open embedded in the code editor

Tags: javascript, node.js

I installed a plugin, and now when I use npm (node package manager) it changed terminal to open in an external program, runs it's code, and close it instead of appearing in the embedded terminal so I can see what it did.

It didn't use to do this.  How do I get the info to appear back in Visual Studio Code instead of opening up an external terminal to process my command?

Comment: even if I use powershell or VSC, no matter what, if I type node script.js it no longer runs in the desired terminal (including npm install functions), it opens up a separate instance of node or npm, quickly does its thing and closes providing no feedback.  I want it all to appear in the embedded terminal of VSC

Comment: /bump need help with this